# header shown two times when using jquery tabs

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, header

I got a weird error (i use **codeigniter**), the header and jquery tabs is shown two times :

[image]

This is my `header_v`, the place for the jquery tabs :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>

<div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="umat">Daftar Umat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Daftar Pengurus</a></li>
            <li><a href="absensi">Absensi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is `umat_v`, the view that will loaded when the first tab is clicked :

```
<body>
    <div id="form_search">
        <?php echo form_open('backend/index') ?>
            <p>
            Kelas :
            <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas1', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');?> -
            <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas2', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');?>
            </p>
            <p>
            Nama : <?php echo form_input('txt_nama');?>
            Alamat : <?php echo form_input('txt_alamat');?>
            Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
            </p>
            <?php echo form_submit('btn_search', 'Search');?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $table ?>
        <?php echo $pagination ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is the `controller` i used to load those views :

```
public function umat() {
    $this->load->view('template/header_v');
    //check authorization
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
        redirect('backend');

    //pagination
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend/umat/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->backend_m->count_umat();
    $config['per_page'] = 10; 
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //table     
    $data_umat = $this->backend_m->get_umat();

    $this->table->set_heading(
        'No',
        'Nama',
        'Kelas',
        'Alamat',
        'Sekolah',
        'Nomor Telepon',
        'Keterangan'        
    );

    $no = 1;
    foreach($data_umat as $list_temp) 
    {
        $this->table->add_row(
            $no++,
            $list_temp->nama,
            $list_temp->kelas,
            $list_temp->alamat,
            $list_temp->sekolah,
            $list_temp->no_tlpn,
            $list_temp->keterangan
        );
    }


    $data_kelas = $this->backend_m->get_kelas();

    $data['list_kelas'][0] = 'Pilih Kelas';

    foreach($data_kelas as $row)
    {
        $data['list_kelas'][$row->kelas_id] = $row->kelas;
    }

    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

    $this->load->view('backend/umat_v', $data);
}
```

Why my header/`header_v` always loaded 2 times? Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you have this line right at the beginning of your function:

```
$this->load->view('template/header_v');
```

So as far as I can see, you are loading the template again, including the header and (as you can probably see in your screenshot) the list items, too.

Therefore I think you need to specify another template to be used.

---

To have more room for the ongoing discussion in the comments, here an edit:

You need two different controllers, one for the page and one for each tab. In the main controller you display your header with

```
$this->load->view('template/header_v');
```

But in each tab you must not include the header anymore! Since you included hrefs in the list items, jQuery Tabs will load the content via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D
Yes, i have that code because i want to include the view one times. Can you explain more?what should i do and what is my mistake? :D

Comment: And i dont load the view in the constructor, i just load it one time in the method :D

Comment: Well in your `umat` method only produce the code that should be included *inside* the tab (therefore removing the above mentioned line in the `umat` method might be enough (I don't now what framework you're using, so no guarantee for that)

Comment: Sorry i forget to say that i use codeigniter. If i remove that line, the header will not be loaded...

Comment: So just to clarify, you *do* use two different URLs for your first tab and the "main page"? I thought that's what you wanted - remove the header from the inside tab?

Comment: I use two views, one for the header, and one for the content. yes, iwant to  remove the header from the inside tab. I think it has something to do with the code you mention above. But, if i remove it, the header will not be shown :D

Comment: Thanks for the edit :D so i have to use a sparate controller. Now i have removed the header in the tab, but im confuse HOW to use 2 controllers in one page?sorry im new in CI :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27410/discussion-between-michael-rose-and-blaze-tama)

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I finally understand what you mean and its working now :D