# html vertical auto scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, scroll, scrollbar

Im new with pure `javascript` (well i found its easy to use `jquery`, but its too bad i cant use `jquery` in this case :D).

I tried to follow this [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/DG8yR/), but its not working in my web.

This is a screen shoot and **explanation** of my web :

[image]

So, this page is separated into 2 different html file, one for header and its jquery tabs, the other one for the content below the tab.

My plan is to let the content below the jquery tabs scrollable, so the **following code** is from the html of my **content** (**below the jquery tabs**):

```
<body>
    <script type="javascript">
        function top() {
        document.getElementById( 'top' ).scrollIntoView();    
    };

    function bottom() {
        document.getElementById( 'bottom' ).scrollIntoView();
        window.setTimeout( function () { top(); }, 2000 );
    };

    bottom();
</script>

<div id="form_search">
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <?php echo form_open('backend/index') ?>
        <p>
        Kelas :
        <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas1', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');?> -
        <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas2', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');?>
        </p>
        <p>
        Nama : <?php echo form_input('txt_nama');?>
        Alamat : <?php echo form_input('txt_alamat');?>
        Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
        </p>
        <?php echo form_submit('btn_search', 'Search');?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $table ?>
    <?php echo $pagination ?>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Please note that the top and bottom div is just for the page limit (i followed the sample code above).
I have tried another way like change the id/element used for limit, but its still not working.

Thank you for your help :D

Note : i use `codeigniter` framework for this project :D

Comment: which ever div that has the content you want to be scrollable simply just add this  `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: Why are you using two HTML tags?

Comment: @PrakashChennupati sorry im fairly new to web-programming :D, so i just need to put that css code to my body tag?*will googling for it* :D

Comment: @PixelHorror because i use jquery tabs..(sorry i cant explain much, im still learning :D), well i use separated html because of my previous question about jquery tabs in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765937/header-shown-two-times-when-using-jquery-tabs :D

Comment: It *looks* like you're using the jQuery UI stylesheet (the lightness theme, to be exact) but, are you using the jQuery javascript library?

Comment: Why don't you use <section> or <div> tags to separate your content? It doesn't really make much sense to create diferent documents for a single page.

Comment: @PixelHorror Again, i cant explain much..its just because i got the "double header" error (the link is in my previous comment) and one senior give me a way to fix it :D
However, i think its because the content will be changed everytime i click a different tab, and if i combine it in one html, the header and tabs will be shown two times :D

Comment: @couzzi yes, i use that :D Sorry what do you mean by javascript library?(jquery?)my only script to achieve this plan is only on the body tag (see my code above). Thanks :D

Comment: Do the tabs work? If so, you're using the jQuery UI javascript library. Inside your `<script>` tag put this `alert($.fn.jquery)` — what does it say when you reload the page?

Comment: @couzzi let us continue on your answer :D

Comment: @BlazeTama oh wonderful, its a simple fix then. I posted my answer below. please remember to mark as correct answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the solution to the user's question was to simply add `overflow-y:scroll` into the css for the div tag where the content was being placed. simple solution

Answer (score 1):

#### jQuery

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#bottom').offset().top }, 2000);

      ^                                    ^                        ^
What to scroll ---------------------- to which element --------- duration
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and a very clear explanation :D
But, its still not working. I have tried to put your code in the header(html1 document) and in the content(html2 document, the code in my question) but neither of them is working. Maybe i did some mistake? :D

Comment: Yes Sir, the tabs is working fine :D and i got 1.9.1 when i use your alert. I just got an error in my firebug,it said : TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined :D

Comment: its working now! i put it in the script on my body tag (in my question's code, its the content below the jquery tabs), but now i just can see the content page (my header and tabs is disappear, they become too high and i cant scroll up) :D

Comment: Yeah, I only just realized there's a ton of code at the wayyyy bottom of the `HTML` window in your original Fiddle. Also, don't put Javascript in the `HTML` section, put it in the `Javascript` section.

Comment: Oh...i just realized it....and it makes me really confuse @@ do you have any idea to help me? (cant understand the fiddle). THanks :D

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you have an example (that works) of what you're trying to do? Also, a friendly suggestion—don't use multiple emoticons (or any, at all, ever) in your questions/comments as it's distracting.

Comment: okay, thanks for your suggestion. Sorry for my bad habit, i think i will stop it

Comment: No need to apologize, just trying to help and make sure you get the best responses to to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a lot of extra stuff in the bottom of your html screen in fiddle. I took that out and adjusted some of the javascript. 
But taking the extra out did the trick already ...

```
// extra stuff starting at line 332

    <script>

        /* by: thinkingstiff.com
        license: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/ */

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-555555-6']);
        // more stuff
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/pA9QZ/3/

Comment: sorry Sir, what do you mean? :D and the fiddle is NOT my code, my code is provided in the question, the fiddle is just for my sample code

Comment: Thanks Sir, i just realized theres much more code in the fiddle @@
Do you have any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: To add scroll, add overflow-y: auto;
Another thing that can be considered is using a div as a wrapper inside the tab and have that one generate the scrollbar with the same CSS setting for overflow.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/pA9QZ/4/

For automated scroll I would suggest to use jQuery. Pure javascript is beautiful, bur you would have to do a lot of extra code to get the wanted results which would be avoided by using jquery or another platform that offers animating capability.

Comment: Also take a loot at the scrollTo() function 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, your explanation help me a lot. Its too bad i only can vote up one time.